# How to get the data defined in layout class component file used for livewire full page component as base layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am having a small issue with not getting the data defined in the layout class file while using the Livewire component as a full-page component. The layout file

```
// \App\View\Components\AppLayout.php           
class AppLayout extends Component {
   public function render() {
         $menus = [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'link' => '/'],
            ...
         ];
         return view('layouts.app', ['menus' => $menus]); // this works fine with other blade templates
   }
}
```

And here is the livewire component i want to use as full page component

class SearchPage extends Component
{
public $query;

```
protected $queryString = ['query'];

public function mount() {
}

public function render()
{
    $products = Product::with(['category'])
    ->search($this->query)
    ->published()
    ->get();

    
    return view('livewire.search-page', [
        'products' => $products
    ])->layout(\App\View\Components\AppLayout::class);
}
```

}

The route is defined as

```
//web.php
Route::get('/search', SearchPage::class);
```

When I visit this endpoint, there is an error $menus is not defined. What am I missing here? I don't want to repeat the $menus code in two separate places. I am also aware that I can define public $menus inside the livewire component and pass that variable to the layout from within that component.

Comment: Where does `$menus` come from in the layout component?

Comment: @Yinci $menus is defined just above the render function in the layout component.

Comment: I was trying to set it up quickly in one of my projects but I didn't even get it to render. What version of Laravel and Livewire are you using?

Comment: @Yinci it's livewire 3 and laravel 10

Comment: I seem unable to extend Livewire with another Livewire component. I can create a layout blade file with a `{{$slot}}` and extend that just fine. I can also add Livewire components inside that layout, and it works as expected. So, I'll have to ask you how you are able to use another Livewire component as layout, and secondly, if there's anything wrong with using a simple blade layout that includes a Livewire component.

Comment: @Yinci No I am not using Livewire as a layout component. AppLayout is a simple blade component. What I am using is a full-page livewire component in the route.

Comment: All the livewire component by default uses layouts/app.blade.php. I solved it by creating a new blade file and placing the livewire component inside the blade file. But it kinda feels not right as I have a whole blade page containing just a single livewire component.